# What is affecting on will Vue computed property re-computed or no?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-property-decorator

I expect that `currentSelectionViewContent` will be re-computed each time when `selectedOptionsIndexes` has changed. Really, sometimes it works, sometimes - not.

```js
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
  template
})
export class SelectField extends Vue {

  private onNewOptionSelected(newOption: SelectField.Option, indexInArray: number): void {

    console.log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedOptionsIndexes, null, 2));

    this.selectedOptionsIndexes[0] = indexInArray;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedOptionsIndexes, null, 2));
    console.log("--------------");

    if (isUndefined(newOption.key)) {
      this.$emit("change", newOption.relatedEntity);
    } else {
      this.$emit("change", newOption.key);
    }
  }

  // Vue computed property in "vue-property-decorator" syntax
  private get currentSelectionViewContent(): string {
    console.log("Recomputing ...");
    switch (this.selectedOptionsIndexes.length) {
      case 0:
        return SelectField.DEFAULT_NOTHING_SELECTED_PLACEHOLDER;
      case 1:
        return this.selectOptions[this.selectedOptionsIndexes[0]].title;
      default:
        return SelectField.DEFAULT_MULTIPLE_OPTIONS_SELECTED_LETTERING;
    }
  }
}
```

Working case:

[image]

Not working case (no re-computing):

[image]

I sorry about was not created the repro for this case (the reproducing of component where this problem causes, it's dependencies and also environment) takes too long time. If you can not understand what wrong here without repro, please just teach me what is affecting on will Vue computed property re-computed or no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue has certain behavior around arrays to be aware of. From [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays):

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> - When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
>   vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
> - When you modify the length of the
>   array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

To ensure Vue sees your array change, always make a copy of the array and re-assign it, like this:

```
var updatedIndexes = [...this.selectedOptionsIndexes]; // Copies array
updatedIndexes[0] = indexInArray; // Update the copy
this.selectedOptionsIndexes = updatedIndexes; // Overwrite with copy
```