# Vue computed property has not been updated although the array from which it depends has been explicitly reassigned

Tags: typescript, vue.js

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63294943/4818123) on question [What is affecting on will Vue computed property re-computed or no?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293814/what-is-affecting-on-will-vue-computed-property-re-computed-or-no) I knew that

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
> vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue When you modify the length of the
> array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

Here is definitely other case because I **explicitly assigning** the new value to array.

### Target

1. Images slider must display currently selected photo
2. When `photosURLs` array is empty, slider should display dummy image (like "no image") instead.
3. When `product.photosURLs` updated, slider must display updated photo (or dummy, if all photos has been deleted).

### Implementation

Below implementation reaches to first and second target.

#### Markup (pug)

```
.ImageSliderForNarrowScreens
  .ImageSliderForNarrowScreens-ActiveImage-DefaultBackgroundUnderlay

    .ImageSliderForNarrowScreens-ActiveImage-ImageLayer(
      v-if="product.photosURLs.length < 2"
      :style="`background-image: url(${activeProductPhotoURL_ForImagesViewer});`"
    )

    template(v-else)
      .ImageSliderForNarrowScreens-ActiveImage-ImageLayer(
        :key="'IMAGE_SLIDER-IMAGE-'+activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer"
        :style="`background-image: url(${activeProductPhotoURL_ForImagesViewer});`"
        v-touch:swipe.left="switchImagesSliderToPreviousPhoto"
        v-touch:swipe.right="switchImagesSliderToNextPhoto"
      )
```

#### Logic (TypeScript)

Images slider refers to `product.photosURLs`.

- When user switched to editing mode, `product.photosURLs` will be copy to `uploadedProductPhotosURLs`, the array of updated but not submitted yet photos URLs.
- When `uploadedProductPhotosURLs` will be submitted, `uploadedProductPhotosURLs` will be copy to `product.photosURLs`;

```js
import { Vue, Component, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";


@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {

  private product!: Product;
  private uploadedProductPhotosURLs: Array<string> = [];

  /* --- Product photos viewing ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
  private activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer: number = 0;

  private get activeProductPhotoURL_ForImagesViewer(): string {
    if (this.product.photosURLs.length === 0) {
      return PRODUCT_DUMMY_PHOTO_URL;
    }
    return this.product.photosURLs[this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer];
  }

  // --- Well, it does not matter, I just mentioned it in template
  private switchImagesViewersToNextProductPhoto(): void {
    this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer =
      this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer !== this.product.photosURLs.length - 1 ?
        this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer + 1 : 0;
  }

  private switchImagesViewersToPreviousProductPhoto(): void {
    this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer =
      this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer !== 0 ?
        this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer - 1 : this.product.photosURLs.length - 1;
  }
  // ------------------------------------------------------------


  /* --- Submitting of changes ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
  private async onClickSaveProductButton(): Promise<void> {

    try {

      await ProductsUpdatingAPI.submit({
        // ...
        productPhotosURLs: this.uploadedProductPhotosURLs
      });


      console.log("checkpoint");
      console.log("uploadedProductPhotosURLs:");
      console.log(this.uploadedProductPhotosURLs);

      console.log("'product.photosURLs' before updating:");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.product.photosURLs, null, 2));

      this.product.photosURLs = this.uploadedProductPhotosURLs;
      // normally, I must set it to 0, but for now it does not affect
      // this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer = 0;
      console.log("'product.photosURLs' after updating:");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.product.photosURLs, null, 2));

    } catch (error) {

      // ....
    }
  }
}
```

### Problem

When `this.product.photosURLs` is empty, let's try to add and submit new photos. The debug output will be:

```
checkpoint
uploadedProductPhotosURLs:
[
  "https://XXX/c732d006-1261-403a-a32f-f73c0f205aa8.jpeg", 
  "https://XXX/2b7ae2e2-4424-4038-acee-9624d5b937bc.jpeg", 
   __ob__: Observer
]
'product.photosURLs' before updating:
[]
'product.photosURLs' after updating:
[
  "https://XXX/c732d006-1261-403a-a32f-f73c0f205aa8.jpeg",
  "https://XXX/2b7ae2e2-4424-4038-acee-9624d5b937bc.jpeg"
]
```

From the view point of algorithm, all correct, but computed property `activeProductPhotoURL_ForImagesViewer` (getter in TypeScript OOP syntax) has not been recomputed!
It means, `PRODUCT_DUMMY_PHOTO_URL` is still displaying.

```
private get activeProductPhotoURL_ForImagesViewer(): string {
  if (this.product.photosURLs.length === 0) {
    return PRODUCT_DUMMY_PHOTO_URL;
  }
  return this.product.photosURLs[this.activeProductPhotoArrayIndexForImagesViewer];
}
```

Same if to delete images: debug output is matching to expected, but cached image that has been deleted is still displaying!

```
checkpoint
uploadedProductPhotosURLs:
[__ob__: Observer]
'product.photosURLs' before updating:
[
  "https://XXX/c732d006-1261-403a-a32f-f73c0f205aa8.jpeg",
  "https://XXX/2b7ae2e2-4424-4038-acee-9624d5b937bc.jpeg"
]
'product.photosURLs' after updating:
[]
```

Same if to replace images.

Comment: You use `product!: Product` but you are not showing where you initialize it into reactivity. A common pattern is to assign some default. In this case it should be at least `product = { photosURLs: []}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on @Estradiaz's comment, and as mentioned in Vue's own documentation: [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html),

> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.

you either need to initialize `product.photosURLs` maybe with an empty array, or else you need to use `Vue.set()` in order to assign value to `this.product.photosURLs` in your `onClickSaveProductButton` function, like this:

```
Vue.set(this.product, 'photosURLs', this.uploadedProductPhotosURLs);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I see, it's better to not definite assignment assertions in Vue. Want to do it when the big object entity must be fetched after component created ....

Comment: @Takesi There are actually proper uses for definite assignment assertions in Vue. For instance, it should be used when declaring a [`@Prop`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#Prop) because the variable is automatically initialized by the lib.